# Delivering C SW module as source code Vs Library

Tags: c, object, embedded

I'm using C language for my embedded programming (ie. target is a microcontroller), and I'm in a situation to deliver my SW module as object code (library), that will be used by customer team.

Usually I used to deliver my SW as source code and I know the constraints on how to integrate (compile, link source code) but I don't know what are the constraints for obj(library) code integration at customer side.

for ex: - is it mandatory to have the same compiler as mine?
        - is it mandatory to regenerate each time this library for customer once he will change compiler options, linker options etc...

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Simo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer very much depends on the target support.  You may have to provide libraries for all combinations of:

- instruction set,
- endianness,
- FPU support,
- debug support,
- core variant

and possibly more.  For example, a particular RTOS I use that targets ARM Cortex-M3, 4 and 7 generates in the order of 20 variants.

The obvious approach is to use a build system that will generate all the required combinations in a single build.

Object code compatability between compilers is by no means a given, so you may also have to build for multiple compilers, which in turn may require a licence 
for each one.  That may be expensive, and in most cases using a trial or evaluation version for code you distribute is disallowed.

An alternative perhaps is to use a source code obfuscator that will render your code virtually unreadable and very hard to modify or reverse engineer, while allowing your customer to compile it for their specific target and desired compiler/linker settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer.
Code obfuscator is an option.

In my context I can ask the team to which I'll deliver to precise the development and target environment.

Best regards.